# After 12.04 release would 10.04 still be LTS?

Tags: 10.04, lts

Silly question, but given that I have upgraded and downgraded from Lucid to Natty and back, and after some months of anticipation, Lucid to Oneiric then back, would the LTS cycle of Lucid end in April?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check here for all the releases and their end of life/schedule and stuff like that - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

According to it, the end of life for Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx is

- April 2013 for the Desktop version
- April 2015 for the Server version

Be clear, that end of life does not mean that Lucid Lynx will be unusable but just that it won't be receiving any active important security updates after that date.

Answer (score 4):

10.04 will end it's LTS life cycle (As mentioned in the Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) in:

- April 2013 (Desktop)
- April 2015 (Server)

The reasons behind this life cycle are here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseManifest but basically it is 3 years Desktop versions and 5 years Server versions.

So you still have some more time to stay with it and enjoy it.

When 10.04 ends it will be remembered. I enjoyed many weekends with it. He always gave it the best he could.

Long live 10.04!

Answer (score 2):

10.04LTS will be supported until April 2013 on the desktop and Apri 2015 on the server. That's 3 and 5 years of support, respectively. New releases doesn't change anything. From 12.04LTS, the support will be five years on both server and desktop, hence it'll be supported until April 2017, though the plan is to release new LTS releases in 2014 and 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If your LTS is deployed on a work bread and butter machine, its always wise to be slow and steady, hold on for six months and then do a fresh clean install of 12.04 Precise Pangolin.